# mysqldumpを実行すると'Illegal mix of collations' Errorが発生する

Tags: mysql

Windows PCのMySQLにて既存のデータベースのダンプを取ろうとして

```
mysqldump -uroot -p testdb > testdb.dump
```

を実行したところ、結果は以下のようなエラーとなりました

```
mysqldump Error: 'Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,CORECIBLE) and (uft8_unicode_ci,CORECIBLE) for operation '='' when trying to dump tablespaces
```

似たようなトラブルをネットで調べてみて以下のようにmysql clientにてデータベース文字コードを確認しましたが、特にutf8_general_ciとutf8_unicode_ciが混在しているように見えませんでした

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%' ;
variable_name | Value
character_set_clinet      | uft8
character_set_connection  | utf8
character_set_database    | utf8
character_set_filesystem  | utf8
character_set_results     | utf8
character_set_server      | utf8
character_set_system      | utf8
character_sets_dir        | c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\
```

```
mysql> show variables like 'coll%' ;
Variable_name | Value
collation_connection  | utf8_unicode_ci
collation_database    | utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server      | utf8_unicode_ci
```

```
mysql> show table status from testDB ;
```

(省略しますが、すべてのテーブルがutf8_unicode_ciであることを確認済）

**MySQL バージョン**
mysqld: ver 8.0.16 for win64 on x86_64
mysql : ver 8.0.16 for win64 on x86_64

どこに問題があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

あてずっぽうですが、mysql と mysqldump で設定が違うということはないですか？ 具体的には my.cnf or my.ini で [mysql] [mysqldump] などのセクションの設定が一致しているか確認してみてください。

Comment: my.iniに[mysqldump]セクションの記述がなかったので[mysql]セクションの内容と同様にdefault-character-set=utf8と記述して再起動しましたが、結果は変わりませんでした